My sidebar button called "Home Background" stops working after login, now it receives a null value in the onPressed

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({
    super.key,
    this.controller,
  });
  final ZoomDrawerController? controller;
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUsername();
  }

  String username = '';
  bool isLoadingUsername = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          widget.controller != null
              ? HomeBackground(
                  onPressed: () => widget.controller!.toggle!(),
                  title: isLoadingUsername
                      ? 'Cargando...'
                      : username.isNotEmpty
                          ? 'Hola,$username'
                          : 'Hola, Invitado!',
                  desc: 'It s time for build your dream\napplication',
                  sidebarIcon: Icons.menu,
                )
              : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          const Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              HomeTypeContent(
                title: 'Choose a Category',
              ),
              HomeContent()
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried to pass the zoomDrawerController as a parameter to the getScreen function that stores the sections inside the mainScreen so the button that opens the sidebar should get that controller, but it keeps getting a null value after login and logout.
